# C++ Inherited Structs

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

I am attempting to decorate a node struct in order to allow for single/double linked lists. I have the following code:

```
    struct node
    {           
        Object* obj;
    };

    struct BasicNode: node
    {
            node* next;
    };
```

When I use the following code, I get an error:

```
temp->next = new BasicNode;
    temp = temp->next;
```

I have defined head as`node* head;`

The compiler gives me the following error: `"struct ListAsSLL::node has no member 'next'"` at my `temp->next`line.

What have I done wrong? Or was I wrong to do struct inheritance?
Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: Downcasting from parent to child class needs to be explicit.

Comment: What the declaration for `head`?

Comment: Inheritance goes one way only. A `BasicNode` is a `node`, but a `node` is not a `BasicNode`. IMO `temp` should be a `BasicNode*` while `head` should be a `node*`.

Comment: While I appreciate you accepting my answer, @GillBates deserves it more for his detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare head as

```
node* head...;
```

Answer (score 7):

`head` is of type `BasicNode`. `BasicNode` inherits `node` which means that if you want to assign to `head` you need *at least* a `BasicNode` which isn't the case here. You need an explicit cast (known as downcasting, parent to child class) if you know `temp` is of type `BasicNode` and you want to use it:

```
head = static_cast<BasicNode*>(temp);
```

Upcasting (from child to parent class) however doesn't require an explicit cast. For example, if you made `head` a type of `node` instead, you wouldn't have to cast it. And since you are only accessing `obj`, this is probably what you wanted.

```
node* head = //something..;

//later on..
node* temp = new BasicNode;
temp->obj = nl;
head = temp;
```

Then later on, if you somehow still know `head` contains a derived object like `BasicNode` you can always explicitly cast it again:

```
BasicNode* basicNode = static_cast<BasicNode*>(head);
```